# php session id value to multiple pages

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to pass the value of a session id to a different page, but only the last product id is passed to the second page no matter if a product with a different id is selected. Ideally what ever product is clicked that id should pass to the second page

```
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
?>

<!--Some other html code -->

  <?php


      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "user";
      $password = "pass";
      $dbname = "dbname";

      // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }

      $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 1 ORDER BY ProductName ASC";
      $myresult = $conn->query($sql2);

       $x = 1;
       while ($row = $myresult->fetch_assoc()) {
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['ProductID'];
       ?>



       <div class="col-sm-4">
                           <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                               <div class="single-products">
                                   <div class="productinfo text-center">

                                      <a href="page2.php"> <img src="../../images/myImages/<?php echo $row['ProductImage1'];?>_0001_1.jpg" alt="../../images/myImages/<?php echo $row['ProductImage1'];?>_0001_1.jpg" /></a>
                                       <h2><?php echo $row['ProductPrice'];?></h2>

 <!-- when i echo $_SESSION['id'] i get correct values for each product -->
                                       <p><?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?></p>    
                                       <p><?php echo $row['ProductName']; ?></p>


 <!-- Other HTML Code -->
```

Second Page after clicking a product and expecting the correct product id to be passed.

```
<body>
<?php

 session_start();
 echo $_SESSION['favcolor'];
 echo $_SESSION['id'];

?>
```

This results in the last Product ID being passed to the second page no matter what product is clicked

Comment: You have output before you start the session.

Comment: Which line are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

When you print the Id's of the products you're retrieving from the table and iterate them in the `while` loop so they're gonna be right. To set the id product in the session when this is clicked you must either set the value in the second page or set it with an AJAX Request, in this case is necessary use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Well because in while loop you override the value each time so at the end you only get last record.

Change your code at two places.

**1. Make array of ids**

```
$x = 1;
$idArray = array(); //define array
while ($row = $myresult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $idArray[] = $row['ProductID']; //push values in array

    //other code..

} // end while
 $_SESSION['id'] = $idArray; //store to session
```

**2. Use data from db not session**

Replace this

```
<p><?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?></p>
```

With this

`<p><?php echo $row['ProductID'];?></p`>

Comment: When i make the above changes i get "Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings" referring to the "$_SESSION['id'][] = $row['ProductID'];" line

Comment: I made a small change, use that and try again